# how to open a new web page on the same tab by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I a button on my web page. its code is:

```
/* code of the other forms  */
<form method="get"  onsubmit="return validation()" > 
     <input type="submit" id="x" value="Search"  onmouseover="mover(this)" onmouseout="mout(this)" /> 
</form>
```

when I click on the button is should validate the value of the other forms and open new web page on the same tab. I have no problem with the validation part. the problem is the new web page opens in a new tab which is not what I want. So far the code is:

```
 function validation(){
    var x=document.forms["flyrics"]["lyrics"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Search without Lyrics?");
        return false;
    }

    var y=document.forms["fartist"]["artist"].value;
    if (y==null || y=="")
    {
        alert("Search without Artist Name?");
        return false;
    }

            window.open("songList.html", "_self");      
}
```

In the last line, it is the code to open new page on the same tab. but each time I click on the button a new tab opens. How do I correct it?
I also tried using the following codes too. but I don't know why none of them worked to open the new page on the same tab.

```
 location.href = "songList";
 window.location="songList.html";
 window.open("songList.html",  "currentWindow", "");
```

Where is the actual problem? need help to fix it.
I need to do this using javascript and html only.

Comment: `window.location` shouldn't open in a new tab unless your browser settings override it.

Comment: exactly,  window.location shouldn't open in a new tab but in my code it does. and I'm confused why it is happening. How do I know my browser is overriding it?

Comment: Try the same page in another browser on your computer.

Comment: window.location.replace(url);  // no history

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to achieve is to validate the search first before submitting the form? You have to add action attribute in the form tab and move the `return validation()` to submit button.

Look at  my example below:

This will allow you to load the `songList.html` on the same Tab.

```js
function validation() {
    var x=document.forms["flyrics"]["lyrics"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
    {
        alert("Search without Lyrics?");
        return false;
    }

    var y=document.forms["fartist"]["artist"].value;
    if (y==null || y=="")
    {
        alert("Search without Artist Name?");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<form id="flyrics">
        <input type="text" id="lyrics" value="">
</form>
<form id="fartist">
        <input type="text" id="artist" value="">
</form>

/* code of the other forms  */
<form id="songList" action="songList.html">
        <input type="submit" id="x" value="Search" onclick="return validation()"/> 
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you just do

```
        window.open("songList.html");
```

Comment: I tried this also. it opens the songList.html into a new tab not in the current tab. :( @Toby

Answer (score 0):

Try using [window.location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location):

```
window.location.assign("songList.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.location.replace("songList.html");
```

This works fine for me!